# What if a werewolf from Twilight Saga imprinted while in wolf form?

Tags: twilight, breaking-dawn

This is a quote from Breaking Dawn by Stephanie Meyer, the last in the Twilight Saga.

> Warm brown eyes, the color of milk chocolate - the exact same color that Bella's had been.
>   My shaking jerked to a stop; heat flooded through me, stronger than before, but it was a new kind of heat - not a burning.
>   It was a glowing.
>   Everything inside me came undone as I stared at the tiny porcelain face of the half-vampire, half-human baby. All the lines that held me to my life were sliced apart in swift cuts, like clipping the strings to a bunch of balloons. Everything that made me who I was - my love for the dead girl upstairs, my love for my father, my loyalty to my new pack, the love for my other brothers, my hatred for my enemies, my home, my name, my self - disconnected from me in that second - snip, snip, snip - and floated up into space.
>   I was not left drifting. A new string held my where I was.
>   Not one string, but a million. Not strings, but steel cables. A million steel cables all tying me to one thing - to the very center of the universe.
>   I could see that now - how the universe swirled around this one point. I'd never seen the symmetry of the universe before, but now it was plain.
>   The gravity of the earth no longer tied my to the place where I stood.
>   It was the baby girl in the blonde vampire's arms that held me here now.
>   Renesmee.

This is the scene at the end of the second part where Jacob imprints on Bella's daughter, Renesmee. So as far as I know, the other few werewolves who imprinted in the series also were in human form when they imprinted:
1. Sam, who saw Emily when she came to visit her cousin, Leah. He could hardly have been in wolf form, since he had to keep the secret from Leah.
2. Quil, who was in Emily's house (also as a human) when her nieces visited her, and met Claire.
3. Jared, who was in school when he saw Kim and imprinted.
4. Paul, who met Rachel on the beach, and couldn't have been in wolf form then.

Also to take note, when the wolves are in their pack (or packs), they can hear each other's thoughts, whether they want to share those thoughts or not. Basically, when in wolf form, they can't block out other wolves' thoughts.

So my question is, what if Jacob (or any other werewolf, for that matter) imprinted while in wolf form? The whole quote above would then have taken place while Jacob was a wolf, and whoever who was in his pack and also in wolf form at the time would have been a witness to it. Would that have made them 'imprint' as well? Or, if not, how would it have affected them?

EDIT: There must be *some* effect on the other wolves who witnessed their brother's imprinting. When Jacob was obsessing over Bella, just before she was married, even Leah said she'd dreamt of kissing Bella, cos she had to share Jacob's love for her when in wolf form together.

Answer (score 1):

So the real question is: why does a Quileute imprint on one person as opposed to another person?

Jacob discusses imprinting with Bella in several places, after he becomes a shape-shifter and his shifting becomes known to Bella. The Quileutes believe that imprinting is as an evolutionary advantage designed to help them identify mates whose genes will help build a strong tribe.

If we accept this belief then we can make some good educated guesses as to what might happen if one of the Quileute imprinted while in wolf form.

First, how would that affect other members of the pack who are also in shifted form? If imprinting is primarily about genetics, then the other pack members would NOT also imprint, since the best match for each wolf would be very different (and especially for a female wolf). The other wolves would experience the thoughts and feelings of the person while they imprinted, and doubtless find it annoying. Jacob mentions that being part of the pack means suffering considerable loss of privacy and the established etiquette is to try to ignore any thoughts or feelings that would not have been normally shared outside the pack bonds. Though Leah would undoubtedly make some kind of snarky comment.

Just to forestall anyone who might wonder, there is no way that a Quileute, shapeshifted or not, would imprint on a wolf while in wolf form. The Quileute are, genetically, mostly human and would not be able to breed with a wolf, which would defeat the whole purpose of imprinting.